# Kinect point cloud all white

Tags: kinect, ros-hydro, openni-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running ros hydro on ubuntu 12.04. The kinect's rgb camera is capturing color images, but the point cloud is all white.

This problem used to be occasional, and sometimes I'd have to power cycle the kinect and unplug/replug all its connections, then launch again and the point cloud would be normal. Now that's not working anymore.

I've tried using drivers `openni_launch` (1.9.5) and `freenect_launch` (0.3.2), but it doesn't make a difference. Ultimately I'd like to be using openni for compatibility with the openni skeleton tracker.

Has anyone seen this problem before? Is there a known solution? If not, what would you recommend as troubleshooting measures?

**Update**: This problem only happens with the PointCloud2. When viewing the DepthCloud in rviz, it's all color.

[image: rviz window showing color image and white point cloud]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212855/kinect-point-cloud-all-white/) by [dinosaur](https://answers.ros.org/users/21732/dinosaur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 233 on 2015-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure you are not disabling depth registration. Depth registration registers colors to the depth points.

Try `roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch depth_registration:=true`.

Check the launch file used to launch the kinect and make sure it does not have a line like `<arg name="depth_registration" value="false" />` in the `openni_launch` node.

---

Originally posted by [dinosaur](https://answers.ros.org/users/21732/dinosaur/) with karma: 233 on 2015-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2